# How to render fullscreen single item in Flatlist?

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

I use Flatlist and I want to implement UI full screen for every item.
I already use `contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1}}` and all parent be flex 1. But every item view is not full screen.

```
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
     <FlatList
      data={["1", "2", "3"]}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
      pagingEnabled={true}
      renderItem={(item) => {
        return (
          <View style={{ height: Dimensions.height, width: Dimensions.width }}>
            <Text>{item.item}</Text>
          </View>
        )
      }}
   />
  </View>
```

Comment: Please add your complete Code

Comment: I updated Tim.  Pls check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a style each component window width and height, using the [Dimensions](https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions). For example;

```js
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

<FlatList
  ...
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <View style={styles.itemWrapper}>{/* Your components */}</View>
  )}
/>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  itemWrapper: {
    width,
    height,
  },
});
```

Comment: do you add background color?

Comment: How can we get the item user is scroll to in flatlist? Thanks İlker